# Error : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, soy algo nuevo en php. Y me sale este error. Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un formulario de pedido. Pero cuando lleno el formulario, en lugar de añadirse los datos a la tabla de pedido me sale este error:

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Este es el codigo de mi formulario:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Pedido

```
<form action ="Pedido.php" method ="post" class= "form-register">

    <h2 class = "form__titulo"> Pedido</h2>
    <div class = "contenedor-inputs">

        <input type ="number" name ="numero" placeholder ="Numero" class = "input-48"  required> 
        <input type ="date" name ="fechacreacion" placeholder ="Fecha creacion" class = "input-48" required> 

        <input type ="date" name ="fechavencimiento" placeholder ="Fecha vencimiento" class = "input-48" required> 
        <input type ="text" name ="condiciones" placeholder ="Condiciones" class = "input-48" required> 

        <input type ="number" name ="subtotal" placeholder ="Subtotal" class = "input-48" required> 

        <input type ="number" name ="iva" placeholder ="IVA" class = "input-48" required> 
        <input type ="number" name ="total" placeholder ="Total" class = "input-100" required > 

        <input type ="text" name ="observaciones" placeholder ="Observaciones" class = "input-100" required >    


        <input type ="submit" value ="enviar pedido" class = "btn-enviar">

    <p> </p>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Y este es mi codigo php:

```
    <?php

include 'conexion.php';



$numero = $_POST["numero"];

$fechac = $_POST["fechacreacion"];

$fechav = $_POST["fechavencimiento"];

$con = $_POST["condiciones"];

$sub = $_POST["subtotal"];

$iva = $_POST["iva"];

$total = $_POST["total"];

$observaciones = $_POST["observaciones"];



$insertar ="INSERT INTO pedido(numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent)VALUES ('$numero','$fechac','$fechav','$con','$sub','$iva','$total','$observaciones')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

if(!$resultado){
 echo mysqli_error($conexion);

}
else
{
echo 'Se ha llenado el formulario con exito';

}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Esta es mi base de datos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que estas diciendo en el `INSERT` mas columnas de las que envias en `VALUES`

```
$insertar ="INSERT INTO pedido(numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent)VALUES ('$numero','$fechac','$fechav','$con','$sub','$iva','$total','$observaciones')";
```

Envias 8 valores cuando esperas 10

Te faltan los campos `Usuario_idUsuario` y `Proveedor_numeroIden`

Comment: Hola,gracias por responder, pero el problema es que Usuario_idUsuario y Proveedor_numeroIden son llaves foráneas. Y esos campos no van en el campo del formulario. ¿Como podria poner esos campos en values?

Comment: Tienes que enviarlas SI O SI, si las pones en el INSERT. De donde salen esos campos? Segun tu modelo 1 es del usuario que esta insertando y otro es el proovedor. @Ghosting que sean llaves foraneas no quiere decir que se agregan solas

Comment: Pero lo que quiero decir es que, debo añadir también esos campos en el formulario html? ¿O hay alguna manera de enviarlos de las otras tablas? Disculpa si mis preguntas te molestan

Comment: Es que eso depende de tu logica. Por ejemplo id de usuario es del usuario que esta logeado? del que esta haciendo el formulario? Lo mismo  con el otro campo, debes seleccionar el proveedor? El usuario logueado tiene proovedores? tienes que verificarlo tu

Comment: Si, el id debe ser del usuario que esta logueado. Pero mi pregunta es como añadiría esos campos.

Comment: tienes algun metodo para obtener los datos del usuario logueado? simplemente deberias obtenerlos y guardarlos en variables, pasarlos en los values

Comment: No, no tengo alguno. ¿Como podria obtenerlos?

Comment: Deberias hacerlo amigo!, la verdad es que como no conozco tu sistema imposible ayudarte. De todas formas mi respuesta soluciona a tu problema. Si tienes otro problema, te recomiendo que generes otra pregunta. Si te sirvio mi respuesta recuerda marcarla como correcta

Comment: No olvides ponerle una nota para que use consultas preparadas, su código es vulnerable a Inyección SQL.